# HornetQ Rest- Publisher-Subscriber messaging

Tags: rest, message-queue, hornetq

Does "HornetQ Rest" support Publisher-Subscriber messaging?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can both *Push* and *Receive* on a [Topic](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/hornetq-rest/1.0-beta-1/userguide/html_single/index.html#d0e215), the answer appears to be yes.